# Creating a contingency table using multiple columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, contingency

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
structure(list(ab = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), bc = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), de = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1), cl = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2)), .Names = c("ab", "bc", 
"de", "cl"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The column cl indicates a cluster association and the variables ab,bc & de carry binary answers, where 1 indicates yes and 0 - No.

I am trying to create a table cross tabbing cluster along with all the other columns in the data frame viz ab, bc and de, where the clusters become column variables. The desired output is like this

```
    1  2  3
 ab 1  3  2
 bc 2  3  1
 de 2  3  1
```

I tried the following code:

```
with(newdf, tapply(newdf[,c(3)], cl, sum))
```

This provides me values cross tabbing only one column at a time.  My data frame has 1600+ columns with 1 cluster column.  Can someone help?

Comment: It seems you could try with `aggregate`; `aggregate(. ~ cl, newdf, sum)`?

Comment: alexis_laz...thank you for a simple execution.  This is really nice, but since my current dataset have 1600+ variables, it becomes a tad bit difficult to read all of them in one go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data is in a half-long half-wide format, and you want it in a fully wide format. This is easiest if we first covert it to a fully long format:

```
library(reshape2)
df_long = melt(df, id.vars = "cl")
head(df_long)
#    cl variable value
# 1   1       ab     0
# 2   2       ab     1
# 3   3       ab     1
# 4   1       ab     1
# 5   2       ab     1
# 6   3       ab     0
```

Then we can turn it into a wide format, using `sum` as the aggregating function:

```
dcast(df_long, variable ~ cl, fun.aggregate = sum)
#   variable 1 2 3
# 1       ab 1 3 2
# 2       bc 2 3 1
# 3       de 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 8):

In `base` R:

```
t(sapply(data[,1:3],function(x) tapply(x,data[,4],sum)))
#   1 2 3
#ab 1 3 2
#bc 2 3 1
#de 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 7):

One way using `dplyr` would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  #group by the varialbe cl
  group_by(cl) %>%
  #sum every column
  summarize_each(funs(sum)) %>%
  #select the three needed columns
  select(ab, bc, de) %>%
  #transpose the df
  t
```

Output:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
ab    1    3    2
bc    2    3    1
de    2    3    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also combine `tidyr:gather` or `reshape2::melt` and `xtabs` to have your contengency table

```
library(tidyr)
xtabs(value ~ key + cl, data = gather(df, key, value, -cl))
##     cl
## key  1 2 3
##   ab 1 3 2
##   bc 2 3 1
##   de 2 3 1
```

If your prefer to use pipe

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -cl) %>%
  xtabs(value ~ key + cl, data = .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update using dplyr's pivot_longer (that supersedes gather) following the code dickoa wrote:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = ab:de,
          names_to = "key",
          values_to = "value") %>% 
xtabs(value ~ key + cl, data = .)
```