# R, how to create a table from a list of occurrences?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file where each occurrence contains two ID's and a number to associate them.
I want to do something simple: I want to create a table where I have the list of the first ID's as rows and the list of the second ID's as columns, and each entry is the numeric value.

Please see the following image:

[image]

I read the file into a dataframe, tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455657/1082019) and use `melt()` but did not succeed.

`df_long = melt(data_table, id.vars = "value")`

How can I create this table? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can use `xtabs(col3 ~ col2 + col1, df1)`

Comment: You could also: `tidyr::spread(df, col1, col3)`

Comment: or `tidyr::pivot_wider`, which is supposed to replace `spread`